# Check whether some element is "focused" without jQuery

Tags: javascript, focus, mootools

I was almost sure I could find the answer here, but I wasn't successful.
How would you check whether is there some object selected (focused) on the moment of the event call? I tried `if (document.activeElement == "[object HTMLBodyElement]")`, but apparently the `.activeElement` is being filled onLoad. I am not allowed to use jQuery, only mootools.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement - as pointed out, if no element is focused, the document body is focused by default:

```
if (document.activeElement != document.body) {
  // something else than the body is focused
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `[object HTMLBodyElement]` is "activeElement" by default. What I don't understand is, why is it not changing when I change the focus to textarea for example.

Comment: if 'nothing' is focused then document.activeElement is <body>

Comment: @mrkva `[object HTMLBodyElement]` is the "stringification" of the body element. This is not actually the contents of `document.activeElement`, but the text `alert()` shows when trying to "output" an object. Do you change the focus to another element and in the same function, reading the value of `document.activeElement`? Maybe the browser does not update the UI when executing a function, but only after the function/event returned?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( document.body === document.activeElement ) {
  // the body is focused, ie no other element is focused
}
```