# Get a value from click on an option

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.sela > option').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
  <option>lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

So click on `lorem` should set `lorem`, click on `ipsum` should set `ipsum` in console, regardless whether option is changed or not.

Is it possible?

Comment: You just need to provide a ‘value’ attribute to the options and it will automatically set the value of the select. If you want to tap into what was selected then you can just listen for the ‘change’ event in the select itself.

Comment: @YongQuan and @dnak, I don't need `change` event, but `click` on an option

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, there is no answer on your link. Just tryings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242857/519413 That is as close as you're going to get to what you require as you're attempting to use a standard control in an improper manner. If you want this behaviour *exactly* then you will need to roll your own custom control, or hack around something like Select2

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, so your comment is the answer, and not the linked posts .

Answer (score 1):

You could try waiting for a change to the element, then using `console.log` to display the value.

```js
$('.sela').on('change', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      $value = $this.val();

  console.log($value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
<option>lorem</option>
<option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: once again - I don't need `change` event but `click` on an option, regardles option is changed or not

Comment: @qadenza Hmm, what about if the `console.log` triggers every time the select is clicked. Would that be suitable?

Comment: unfortunatelly no, `option` must be clicked

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, but I would first generate the value in every option and then you can simply select it with jQuery :

```
$('.sela option[value="1"]')
```

if you don't have values yet, you'll need to identify each option, the easiest way to do is to increment a counter. Or to use the option's text if you are 100% sure you won't have the same using `$(".sela option[value="1"]").text()` or `$(this).find("option:selected").text();`

If you don't even know how to add an option, loop over the select and replace every option :)

**EDIT :**

```
var allOptions = $('.sela')[0];

for(var i=0; i < allOptions.length; i++) {
    console.log(allOptions[i].value);
    allOptions[i].option = new Option('My option', 'i');
}
```

Comment: you can even get the text of the option

Comment: yep just edited it :)

Comment: add values in my example - doesn't work

Comment: Can you just please show me what you did, and what's not working

Comment: @YongQuan, pls do it yourself, bacause it will change the point of my post. Add values to my options and try

Comment: It works, just edited the jquery selector, as I just forgot to select the first select using [0]. Now using my code, simply create a variable that will save the change and remove your onChange trigger